# Find the Size of Each Node

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph

I am having a tree rooted at `1` , i need to find the size of it's each node.
I am using this recursive call in order to do

```
find_size(int curr , int parent){
       S[curr]=1
       for(int j:Children[curr]){

               if(j==parent) continue;
                find_size(j,curr)
                S[curr]+=S[j];
     }

}
```

How to reduce my solution to `non recursive one` , using stacks or something ? Since recursive solution does not work for large data set.

Answer (score 0):

I will describe one possible iterative approach, which consists of two steps:

1. use a queue to determine the depth of each node.
2. process the nodes in decreasing depth order.

This approach is based on a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) traversal of the tree, thus it does not directly mimic the [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) traversal which is done recursively, and has the advantage of being easier to implement iteratively.

---

For step 1:

- initially, add into the queue only the root node, mark it with depth = 0.
- while the queue is not empty, extract the first node from the queue, look at its depth (denoted here as `currentDepth`), and add its children to the end of the queue by marking each with `childDepth` = `currentDepth` + 1.

For step 2:

- process the nodes in the reverse depth order. The processing of a node involves computing its sub-tree size, by adding the sizes of all children (plus 1, for the current node).
- note that each time a node is processed, the children were already processed (because all nodes with higher depth were already processed), thus we already know the sizes of the children sub-trees.

---

Remark:

For step 2, sorting the nodes in decreasing depth order can be done efficiently by implementing the queue from step 1 with a list from which we never actually remove elements (*e.g.* the queue head can be kept using a pointer, and only this pointer can be incremented when polling).

Processing this list in reverse order is all that is needed in order to traverse through the nodes in decreasing depth order. Thus, it is not really necessary to explicitly use the `depth` field.

---

The implementation of the above ideas would look like this:

```c
void find_size() {
    // Step 1
    int queue[numNodes];
    queue[0] = 1;   // add the root in the queue
    int start = 0;
    int end = 1;

    while (start < end) {
        int node = queue[start++];    // poll one node from the queue
        for (int i: Children[node]) { // add its children to the end
            queue[end++] = i;
        }
    }

    // Step 2
    for (int i = end - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int node = queue[i];
        S[node] = 1;
        for (int j: Children[node]) {
            S[node] += S[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You denote the node by indices, therefore I guess you have them represented as two arrays as follows:

```java
int[] parent; // index of parent (the parent of the root is negative, e.g. -1)
int[][] children; // indices of children for each node
```

You can collect the sums starting from the leaf nodes and proceed upwards as soon as you know the result of all children O(n):

```java
s = new int[parent.length];
int[] processed = new int[parent.length]; // the number of children that are processed
for (int i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) // initialize
    s[i] = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
    if (children[i].length == 0) { // leaf node
        int p = parent[i], j = i;
        while (p >= 0 && processed[j] == children[j].length) { // all children are processed
            s[p] += s[j]; // adjust parent score
            processed[p]++; // increase the number of processed child nodes for parent
            j = p; // parent becomes the current node
            p = parent[j]; // and its parent the parent
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But Time Compexity is `O(N*N)`

Comment: @NarendraModi it is O(n), edited the answer, the check for the root was missing.

Comment: It is mimicking the 2nd part of a DFS when returning (therefore starting from the leaves and not the root), the nodes will be processed in exactly the same order.